# How to detect if a signal is audio

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition, microphone, adc

I have a stream of samples collected from a 12-bit ADC that is connected to a microphone-pre-amplifier bundle. Since the sample is 12 bit, so I can assume the they range from 0-4096 in decimal values. After I shifted it down by 2048 and divide by 2048 to obtain a set of samples with in -1 and +1, I should get a nice waveform that represents the audio stream.

(Up to this point, please correct me if I am wrong.)

What I obtained from that linear mapping is a set of samples "oscillates" around -0.55ish. (Usual audio stream samples oscillates around 0)

I am not exactly sure whether to shift and scale again to obtain a waveform that oscillates around 0, or there is something I am doing wrong with the ADC. In either case, I want to know how to determine if my output is an audio stream or a set of random useless samples. Thank you guys!

Comment: The quickest/easiest method is to just play the stream and see what it sounds like.

Comment: Any data is an audio stream if you play through speakers. Perhaps you can clarify exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DC Offset Or [DC Bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_bias) is a property present in various types of electronic signals and ADC converters.

["DC blocking"](http://www.embedded.com/design/embedded/4007653/DSP-Tricks-DC-Removal) or "DC Removal" eliminates any DC component from the audio signal before being processed removing any signal offset.

Comment: A high-pass filter is one way of eliminating your DC Offset problem.